# Need idea for retrieving old chat history between two users

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please help me To find a solution

- Table name = individual chat
- Columns::

  ```
  ID, OppenentId, message, userid, posteddate
  ```

This is table design which is using to store my message please give idea for me how to receive the messages to show similar to chat history

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select message 
from [individual chat]
where userid=xxx
order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

select UserId,OpponentID,Message from IndividualChat where UserId=1 and OpponentID=2 or UserId=2 and OpponentID=1 order by ID desc